# Chrome AutoSelectCertificateForUrls OSX

Tags: macos, google-chrome, settings, ssl

I have a client SSL certificate for authentication. I'm trying to map it to a URL in Chrome on OSX, however the [Chromium documentation](http://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#AutoSelectCertificateForUrls) is of no use.

I have no idea what file to put the **AutoSelectCertificateForUrls** preference in. My guess is it will be some file in *~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default*, based on [this](http://www.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory).

Best I can do is find some random files with *.json* extensions via `find`. They're all extensions and have bizarre paths, e.g.

> Default/Extensions/pjkljhegncpnkpknbcohdijeoejaedia/7_1/_locales/nl/messages.json

Can someone tell me what file to put the **AutoSelectCertificateForUrls** setting in?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The preference goes in the **com.google.Chrome.manifest** file.

1. Open the manifest folder with the following Terminal command.

   ```
   open /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/Resources/com.google.Chrome.manifest/Contents/Resources/
   ```

   <sup>This presumes Google Chrome is in /Applications; adjust if necessary. Make sure to copy the entire line.</sup>
2. Open **com.google.Chrome.manifest**. I will use TextMate.
3. The **AutoSelectCertificateForUrls** preference goes on line 174.

   Alternatively, use ⌘F to search for AutoSelectCertificateForUrls then select the `pfm_targets` array.

   [image]
4. Replace `user-managed` with your preference string, per the [example in the link you gave](http://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#AutoSelectCertificateForUrls).

   ```
   {\"pattern\":\"https://www.example.com\",\"filter\":{\"ISSUER\":{\"CN\":\"certificate issuer name\"}}}
   ```

---

Alternatively, you can use **Workgroup Manager** to set the preference.

1. [Download](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1698) and open Workgroup Manager.
2. Connect to **localhost** with an admin account.

   [image]
3. Choose the **User** tab, and enter your username, then select your account.

   [image]
4. Select **Preferences** in the toolbar, and choose the **Details** tab.

   [image]
   [image]
5. Add Google Chrome or Chromium to the list by clicking the **+** button and selecting the application bundle.

   [image]
6. Double-click the application that you want to add the preference to, or click it and click the pencil <sub>[image]</sub> button.
7. Click **Always**, then choose **New Key**.

   [image]
8. Click **New Item**, and select **Automatically select client certificates for these sites**.

   [image]
9. Click **New Key**.
10. Double-click the **Value** for 0.

    [image]
11. Enter your desired preference string into the box and press enter.
12. Click **Apply Now**, then **Done**.
13. A managed <sub>[image]</sub> icon should appear next to the app that you added the preference to.

    [image]

Comment: I have a feeling you're right, but I've put the line in place and Chrome still prompts me. I've even restarted Chrome several times. For the value of _CN_, I'm using the _Common Name_ in the _Issuer Name_ section of the certificate details in Keychain Access. It's the same thing that shows next to _Issued By_ at the top of that window. I'm using the straight URL for the pattern, no regex or wildcards. Any ideas why it isn't working?

Comment: @quickshiftin Once you've saved the preference, go to chrome://policy and click Reload Policies. The preference should show in the list of policies if this was successful.

Comment: Cool, it's showing the value for _AutoSelectCertificateURL_ as not set. Maybe I'm editing the wrong file? I checked and Chrome is definitely installed under the Applications folder. I tried changing another policy, _AutoFillEnabled_ and after refreshing the policies, it too appears to be not set.

Comment: @quickshiftin I've added an alternative method through Workgroup Manager :)

Comment: Thanks, I went through these steps. **Automatically select client certificates for these sites** isn't in the list when I clicked _New Item_. I tried adding it with the _edit_ button to look like what you have. I didn't see the file get updated on disk though. Maybe something is broken on my install at this point? Check these links: http://i289.photobucket.com/albums/ll238/quickshiftin/ScreenShot2013-11-13at123637PM_zpsa8691b45.png http://s289.photobucket.com/user/quickshiftin/media/ScreenShot2013-11-13at123040PM_zps477762e5.png.html

Comment: @quickshiftin When you mention that you didn't see the file being updated, are you referring to the file in method 1? This is not the same file that is updated through Workgroup Manager, but I'm unsure exactly which one *is* updated though :)

Comment: Yes, I was looking for the file from method 1 to be updated. Either way though, it's strange in method 2 how **Automatically select client certificates for these sites** doesn't show in the list for me. Also, after completing method 2 and running _Reload Policies_ at _chrome://policy/_, still the policy does not show.

Comment: @quickshiftin Is there [anything](http://cl.ly/SSJo) [else](http://cl.ly/SSyo) [missing](http://cl.ly/SSzn) from the list?

Comment: Not that I can tell. My thought was something was busted from the edits I made when trying method 1, but I put them all back to normal. I have a feeling it's updating the file from method 1, because it was complaining about a parse error the first time I tried to use Workgroup Manager. Seems like the file should be all good now, but I can't get **Automatically select client certificates for these sites** to show up in the list. Not sure what to do.., restart Chrome, restart OSX, reinstall Chrome, lol? Hopefully not the last option!

Comment: @quickshiftin Here's my unedited backup of the [manifest file](http://f.cl.ly/items/142z2E371R313C1X220l/com.google.Chrome.manifest) - try replacing yours with this and then seeing if the key shows in the Workgroup Manager list. Yes, it does read the file to find the list of keys, but I believe that there is data elsewhere.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11484/discussion-between-quickshiftin-and-grgarside)

Comment: A colleague has confirmed method 2 (Workgroup Manager) works. Not sure, but I think there's something wrong with my install, which is why I wasn't able to confirm on my laptop.

Answer (score 10):

On Yosemite, that Workgroup Manager app doesn't work, neither did modifying the plist.

This worked for me, in a terminal:

```
defaults write com.google.Chrome AutoSelectCertificateForUrls -array

defaults write com.google.Chrome AutoSelectCertificateForUrls -array-add -string '{"pattern":"https://[*.]my.domain:8090","filter":{"ISSUER":{"CN":"example.com"}}}'
```

Comment: Awesome, works fine on OS 10.8.5 as well.
Confirm via `defaults read com.google.Chrome`.